# Can I run a 3d.io scene locally (without network connection)?

Tags: aframe, 3d.io

I would love to create a 3d.io aframe scene that loads an apartment including 3d.io furniture without the need for a network connection. How can I do that?

Answer (score 4):

This will be possible using the upcoming "Export" API. It will allow you to download an entire scene and then viewing it offline or using inside desktop applications etc.